# Is there a way to change the eclipse template variable tab order?

Tags: eclipse, templates, progress-4gl, openedge

I'd like to create a code template in eclipse and specify where the user can type in the variable name if there are multiple instances of the same variable, because the code completion is not available at the first instance.

This example is written in Progress ABL, as the variable name is defined before the variable type in this case, but it's not really language related if something like that is possible within the scope of templates in eclipse.

Example:

```
define buffer bTablename for Tablename.
```

Template:

```
define buffer b${tablename} for ${tablename}.
```

But I want to start writing at the second ${tablename}, is there a way to change the "tab order" or something to accomplish that?

Comment: I can't really help on this, but I don't see why you would care which field you were in as when you type in one it is mirrored in the other. Then when you finish and tab out you are in neither. Perhaps I am not understanding! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JFace template language](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Ftemplates%2Fpackage-summary.html) doesn't allow to specify a tab order for the template variables.

You would need to either write your own extension for the template completion or contribute changes to Eclipse that introduce that functionality.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, I guess I have to live with it for now.